# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.node_parser'

Tags: python, machine-learning, langchain, huggingface, llama-index

I want to import SimpleNodeParser from llama_index.node parser.

```
from llama_index.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser
```

But when I run this I'm getting an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.node_parser'
```

Help me to solve this.

I want to import SimpleNodeParser from llama_index.node parser.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. You can solve this using

```
from llama_index.core.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser
```

Answer (score 1):

`from llama_index.core.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your llama_index if you are using the current version, kindly use :

### from llama_index.core.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser

Comment: You have reposted the code from the previous two answers verbatim. Please check whether your solution has already been added before posting.